# How do I import a Java library in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Java library pushed on GitHub, and I want to use it in a pipeline.

I tried:

```
@Library('test') _

@Library('test') _
import com.bla.bla.Bla

@Library('test') import com.bla.bla.Bla
```

I always get:

> unable to resolve class Bla.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please refer to https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

As said in the section "**Using third-party libraries**":

*It is possible to use third-party Java libraries, typically found in Maven Central, from trusted library code using the @Grab annotation. Refer to the Grape documentation for details, but simply put:*

```
@Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.4.1')
import org.apache.commons.math3.primes.Primes
void parallelize(int count) {
   if (!Primes.isPrime(count)) {
       error "${count} was not prime"
   }
   // …
}
```

Grape documentation: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#_quick_start

If you want to use a local library or from github the only thing you have to do is to build the project as a maven project and then use **@Grab** accordingly.

Comment: yes, i read it, but is it possible to use libraries from **not** trusted source - local or github?